# Symfony 3 select dinámicos, municipio y provincia

Tags: symfony2, formularios, select2, symfony3

Estoy intentando realizar un formulario de registro donde aparte de los campos habituales nombre, alias, contraseña (`nombre`, `nick` y `password`)... Añado también dos campos dependientes, `Municipio` y `Provincia`.

---

El problema es que solo muestra multiples mensajes de undefined en el campo municipio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

La entidad (`Entity`) que crea el formulario es `DbUsuario`, que tiene el campo `idMunicipio`.

```
/** @var \BackendBundle\Entity\DbMunicipios */
private $idMunicipio;

/**
 * Set idMunicipio
 * @param \BackendBundle\Entity\DbMunicipio $idMunicipio
 * @return DbUsuario
 */
public function setIdMunicipio(\BackendBundle\Entity\DbMunicipio $idMunicipio = null) {
    $this->idMunicipio = $idMunicipio;
    return $this;
}
/**
 * Get idMunicipio
 * @return \BackendBundle\Entity\DbMunicipio
 */
public function getIdMunicipio() {
    return $this->idMunicipio;
}
```

Luego la entidad `DbMunicipio` que conecta con provincia:

```
/** @var \BackendBundle\Entity\DbProvincia */
private $provincia;

/**@param \BackendBundle\Entity\DbProvincia $provincia
 * @return DbMunicipio
 */
public function setProvincia(\BackendBundle\Entity\DbProvincia $provincia = null){
    $this->provincia = $provincia;
    return $this;
}
/**@return \BackendBundle\Entity\DbProvincia */
public function getProvincia(){
    return $this->provincia;
}
```

Y la Entidad `DbProvincia` que solo tiene los campos `id` (`integer`), `slug` (`String`) y `provincia` (`String`).

Defino el formulario de la siguiente manera:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use AppBundle\Form\EventListener\AddProvinciaField;
use AppBundle\Form\EventListener\AddMunicipioField;

class RegistreUserType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
         $factory = $builder->getFormFactory(); 

        $builder->add('nombre', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Nombre',
            'required' => 'required',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'form-nombre form-control')
        ));
        $builder->add('apellido', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Apellido',
            'required' => 'required',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'form-apellido form-control')
        ));
        $builder->add('nick', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Nick',
            'required' => 'required',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'form-nick form-control nick-input')
        ));
        $provinSubscriber = new AddProvinciaField($factory);
        $builder->addEventSubscriber($provinSubscriber);

        $muniSubscriber = new AddMunicipioField($factory);
        $builder->addEventSubscriber($muniSubscriber);

        $builder->add('email', EmailType::class, array('label' => 'Correo electrónico',
            'required' => 'required',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'form-email form-control')
        ));
        $builder->add('password', PasswordType::class, array('label' => 'Password',
            'required' => 'required',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'form-password form-control')
        ));
        $builder->add('Registrarse', SubmitType::class, array("attr" => array("class" => "form-submit btn btn-success")));
    }
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'BackendBundle\Entity\DbUsuario'
        ));
    }
    public function getBlockPrefix() { return 'backendbundle_dbusuario'; }
}
```

Defino dentro de **AppBundle\Form\eventListener** las clases, llamadas en el formulario:

```
AddProvinciaField
namespace AppBundle\Form\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use BackendBundle\Entity\DbProvincia;

class AddProvinciaField implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
     private $factory;

    public function __construct(FormFactoryInterface $factory) {
        $this->factory = $factory;
    }
    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData',
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT     => 'preSubmit'
        );
    }
    private function addProvinciaForm($form, $provincia) {

       $form -> add('provincia', EntityType::class, array(
            'class'         => 'BackendBundle:DbProvincia',
            'label'         => 'Provincia',
            'placeholder'   => '_ Elegir _',
            'auto_initialize' => false,
            'mapped'        => false,
            'attr'=> array('class' => 'form-provincia form-control provincia-input'),
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) {
                $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('provincia');
                return $qb;
            }
        ));
    }
    public function preSetData(FormEvent $event){
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if (null === $data) {return;}

        $provincia = ($data->getIdMunicipio()) ? $data->getIdMunicipio()->getProvincia() : null ;
        $this->addProvinciaForm($form, $provincia);
    }
    public function preSubmit(FormEvent $event) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if (null === $data) { return;}

        $provincia = array_key_exists('provincia-input', $data) ? $data['provincia-input'] : null;
        $this->addProvinciaForm($form, $provincia);
    }
}
```

Y posteriormente defino **AddMunicipioField.php**:

```
 namespace AppBundle\Form\EventListener;

 use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
 use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
 use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryInterface;
 use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
 use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
 use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
 use BackendBundle\Entity\DbProvincia;


class AddMunicipioField implements EventSubscriberInterface {
    private $factory;

    public function _construct(FormFactoryInterface $factory) {
        $this->factory = $factory;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData',
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT     => 'preSubmit'
        );
    }
    private function addMunicipioForm($form, $provincia) {
        $form->add('idMunicipio', EntityType::class, array(
            'class'         => 'BackendBundle:DbMunicipio',
            'label'         => 'Municipio',
            'placeholder'   => '_ Elegir _',
            'auto_initialize' => false,
            'attr'=> array('class' => 'form-municipio form-control municipio-input'),
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) use ($provincia) {
                $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('idMunicipio')
                    ->innerJoin('idMunicipio.provincia', 'provincia');
                if ($provincia instanceof DbProvincia) {
                    $qb->where('idMunicipio.provincia = :provincia')
                    ->setParameter('provincia', $provincia);
                    var_dump($provincia);
                } elseif (is_numeric($provincia)) {
                    $qb->where('provincia.id = :provincia')
                    ->setParameter('provincia', $provincia);
                    var_dump($provincia);
                } else {
                    $qb->where('provincia.provincia = :provincia')
                    ->setParameter('provincia', null);
                    var_dump($provincia);
                }
                return $qb;
            }
        ));
    }
    public function preSetData(FormEvent $event){
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if (null === $data) { return; }

        $provincia = ($data->getIdMunicipio()) ? $data->getIdMunicipio()->getProvincia() : null ;
        $this->addMunicipioForm($form, $provincia);
    }
    public function preSubmit(FormEvent $event){
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if (null === $data) { return; }

        $provincia = array_key_exists('select_provincia', $data) ? $data['select_provincia'] : null;
        $this->addMunicipioForm($form, $provincia);
    }
}
```

Y por último la petición *AJAX*:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.provincia-input').change(function () {
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        var data = $('.provincia-input').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function (html) {
                $('.municipio-input').replaceWith($(html).find('.municipio-input'));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: cómo está definita la ruta que recibe el POST? Has revisado lo que vienen en la respuesta del ajax, por ejemplo mediante chrome devtools?

Comment: Un error que son los **'#provincia-input'** que debe ser **'.provincia-input'**. Ahora el codigo AJAX se executa.
Probando e visto que la consulta sql devuelve null siempre. La request es **backendbundle_dbusuario%5Bprovincia%5D=11** 11 varia según la provincia que se escoja.

Comment: También me sale el error: The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.

Comment: php.ini he cambiado los valores siguientes,

Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 20048M

and ; How many GET/POST/COOKIE input variables may be accepted
max_input_vars = 25000 pero aun persiste el error.

Comment: He resuelto el error de CSRF modificando el script AJAX.

Comment: sigues teniendo errores con tu codigo o ya lo solucionaste? .Saludos

Comment: Sigue fallando ahora el problema es que solo muestra multiples mensajes de undefined en el campo municipio. Tal como se muestra en la imagen.

Comment: Buenas Ángel, de código personalizado no falta nada.. solo una función que llamaría a la vista del formulario de solo 3 linias. Pero eso es código estándar de symfony. Si la verdad ya llevo 1 semana peleándome antes de hacer la publicación y ya no se que probar.

Comment: en su pregunta en SO donde esta el bounty un usuario le dice -> *Can you provide a log of what is returned by the ajax call – Vincent T* y usted modifica la pregunta si quiere notificarlo al usuario puede hacer uso de `@` antes de se nombre al poner `@V` posiblemente se le intentara auto completar algo asi -> @VincentT You can, look at my edit, thanks for your interest. de esta manera le saldra un mensaje en su inbok, espero lo solucione.P.D: yo casi no se programacion web como para ayudarla.Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resuelto:

En el formulario llamo las dos nuevas clases que definiré mas abajo para crear los dos selects dependientes. 'idMunicipio' es como se llama el campo en la Entidad.

```
$builder -> addEventSubscriber(new AddMunicipioFieldSubscriber('idMunicipio'));
$builder -> addEventSubscriber(new AddProvinceFieldSubscriber('idMunicipio'));
```

Primer select, seleccionar provincias.

```
class AddProvinceFieldSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {
private $propertyPathToMunicipio;

public function __construct($propertyPathToMunicipio) {
    $this->propertyPathToMunicipio = $propertyPathToMunicipio;
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return array(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData',
        FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT   => 'preSubmit'
    );
}

private function addProvinceForm($form, $Province = null) {
    $formOptions = array(
        'class'         => 'BackendBundle:DbProvincia',
        'mapped'        => false,
        'label'         => 'Provincia',
        'attr'          => array(
            'class' => 'class_select_provincia',
        ),
    );

    if ($Province) {
        $formOptions['data'] = $Province;
    }

    $form->add('provincia', EntityType::class, $formOptions);
}

public function preSetData(FormEvent $event){
    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();

    if (null === $data) {
        return;
    }

    $accessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();

    $municipio    = $accessor->getValue($data, $this->propertyPathToMunicipio);
    $provincia = ($municipio) ? $municipio->getIdMunicipio()->getProvincia() : null;

    $this->addProvinceForm($form, $provincia);
}

public function preSubmit(FormEvent $event){
    $form = $event->getForm();

    $this->addProvinceForm($form);
}
}
```

Segundo select dependiente de provincias, seleccionar municipios.

```
class AddMunicipioFieldSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

private $propertyPathToMunicipio;

public function __construct($propertyPathToMunicipio){
    $this->propertyPathToMunicipio = $propertyPathToMunicipio;
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents(){
    return array(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA  => 'preSetData',
        FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT    => 'preSubmit'
    );
}

private function addCityForm($form, $province_id){
    $formOptions = array(
        'class'         => 'BackendBundle:DbMunicipio',
        'label'         => 'Municipio',
        'attr'          => array(
            'class' => 'class_select_municipio',
        ),
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) use ($province_id) {
            $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('municipio')
                ->innerJoin('municipio.provincia', 'provincia')
                ->where('provincia.id = :provincia')
                ->setParameter('provincia', $province_id)
            ;

            return $qb;
        }
    );

    $form->add($this->propertyPathToMunicipio, EntityType::class, $formOptions);
}

public function preSetData(FormEvent $event){
    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();

    if (null === $data) {
        return;
    }

    $accessor    = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();

    $municipio        = $accessor->getValue($data, $this->propertyPathToMunicipio);
    $province_id = ($municipio) ? $municipio->getIdMunicipio()->getProvincia()->getId() : null;

    $this->addCityForm($form, $province_id);
}

public function preSubmit(FormEvent $event){
    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();

    $province_id = array_key_exists('provincia', $data) ? $data['provincia'] : null;

    $this->addCityForm($form, $province_id);
} 
}
```

En el controlador añado la siguiente función para recoger el valor id de la provincia y generar la consulta dql.

```
    public function municipioTestAction(Request $request){
    $provincia_id = $request->get('provincia_id');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $provincia = $em->getRepository('BackendBundle:DbMunicipio')->findByProvinceId($provincia_id);

    return new JsonResponse($provincia);
}
```

La funcion findByProvinceId, la creo como una clase nueva tipo repositorio en las entidades donde añado mi funcion nueva para hacer la busqueda.Esta de devuelve un array con las entidades DbMunicipio que busco.

```
class DbMunicipioRepository extends EntityRepository{

public function findByProvinceId($provincia_id){

    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery("
        SELECT muni
        FROM BackendBundle:DbMunicipio muni
        LEFT JOIN muni.provincia provin
        WHERE provin.id = :provincia_id
    ")->setParameter('provincia_id', $provincia_id);

    return $query->getArrayResult();
} 
}
```

Y el codigo AJAX.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".class_select_provincia").change(function(){
    var data = {
        provincia_id: $(this).val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: URL+'/municipio-test',
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {

            var $muni_selector = $('.class_select_municipio');
            alert(data);
            $muni_selector.html('<option>Ciudad</option>');

            for (var i=0, total = data.length; i < total; i++) {
                $muni_selector.append('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].municipio + '</option>');
            }
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Hola Merche. No olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta para cerrar la pregunta como resuelta.